# Is it possible to import content scripts out of project folder for Safari App Extension?

Tags: safari-app-extension

I'm developing a Safari App Extension. But my content scripts are out of Xcode project folder. Is it possible to import those script files?

I see in Apple's official document:

> For each script file, add a dictionary to the array. Each dictionary must have a Script key whose value specifies the path (**relative to the Resources directory of the bundle**) to the script file to include.

Assume my extension project called SafariExt. Folder structure of my app:

```
SafariExt   // Xcode project root folder
 |
 +-- SafariExt Extension
    |
    +--script.js    // this is the default script file in Xcode project, and I specified path relative to this folder


Scripts     // my scripts folder
 |
 +-- myScript.js    // the file I want to import
```

`SafariExt` and `Scripts` are in the same base folder.

Now I'm using `../../Scripts/myScript.js` in Info.plist to refer to `myScript.js` file, but in Safari this file doesn't get loaded.

Info.plist looks like below:

```
<key>SFSafariContentScript</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Script</key>
        <string>../../Scripts/myScript.js</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to load content scripts from the web using `safari.addContentScriptFromURL`. You could try using that in conjunction with `file://` to see if it allows you to pull from outside your project directory.

Really though, you should be copying files into your extension directory with a build script if possible instead of having relative directory links.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariextensions/safariextension/1635361-addcontentscriptfromurl

Comment: The `.addContentScriptFromURL(...)` is part of Safari Extensions JS, which is now deprecated.